# How do you port a SqlServer database to MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SqlServer db that I would like to port to MySQL. What's the best way to to this. Things that need to be ported are:

- Tables (and data)
- FileStream → MySQL equivalent?
- Stored Procedures
- Functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data types are relatively similar.

There is no equivalent to FileStream in MySQL - the files must either be stored as BLOBs, or on the file system while the path is stored in the database.

Migrating away from TSQL means:

- There's no `WITH` clause in MySQL - it will have to converted into a derived table/inline view
- There's no `TOP` syntax - these have to be converted to use `LIMIT`
- There's no ranking/analytic functionality in MySQL - can't use `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` or `NTILE`.  See [this article for alternatives](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html).
- MySQL views have [notoriously limited functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html):

  - The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.
  - The SELECT statement cannot refer to system or user variables.
  - Within a stored program, the definition cannot refer to program parameters or local variables.
  - The SELECT statement cannot refer to prepared statement parameters.
  - Any table or view referred to in the definition must exist. However, after a view has been created, it is possible to drop a table or view that the definition refers to. In this case, use of the view results in an error. To check a view definition for problems of this kind, use the CHECK TABLE statement.
  - The definition cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table, and you cannot create a TEMPORARY view.
  - Any tables named in the view definition must exist at definition time.
  - You cannot associate a trigger with a view.
  - As of MySQL 5.0.52, aliases for column names in the SELECT statement are checked against the maximum column length of 64 characters (not the maximum alias length of 256 characters).
- Dynamic SQL will have to be converted to use MySQL's [Prepared Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) syntax

Answer (score 2):

A [guide/article](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/move_from_microsoft_SQL_Server.html) with some useful tips is available on the official MySQL dev site.

Answer (score 0):

This is not for the faint of heart. Here is an article that explains what you are in for:

```
http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/news/column/0,294698,sid39_gci1187176,00.html
```

Comment: Article links are bad (because links go dead), and in this case, the article requires log-in to read

Comment: @gregmac - Maybe it would have been better for me to paste in all 1,100 words of the article? This link is nine years old, it's not dead and doesn't require a login. So relax a little.